# If there is a database or online collection of images of ceramics, coins, carvings, tools, or other "artifacts" in the public domain

Tags: resource

I just asked [this](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Why-did-the-British-Museum-only-put-images-of-drawings-in-the-public-domain-and-not-images-of-artifacts-such-as-coins-ceramics-carvings-etc) on Quora after realizing that the British Museum (or Library, not sure if they're different) released **public domain** images from **books**, like sketches on Flickr. I remember it being a big headline in the news, "[British Library/Museum releases 1 million images into the public domain](https://britishlibrary.typepad.co.uk/digital-scholarship/2013/12/a-million-first-steps.html#sthash.3kaubTLH.dpuf)".

However, checking the British Museum website for things like ceramics, every image is released under CC BY-NC-SA (Non-Commercial, attribution only). This is hugely restrictive, you couldn't use these images for a book, for example. But they are such good references!

My question is if there is anything like the British Museum collection but that is in the public domain. Something that includes various artifacts of different kinds, such as coins, ceramics, paintings, carvings, tools, fabrics, clothings, etc. I would like to find these *public domain* resources so I can use them in creating textbook material without.

Comment: Yes, the [British Museum](https://www.britishmuseum.org/) and [British Library](https://www.bl.uk/) are different organisations.  The images were released by the British Library.  The reason they were able to do so is in the announcement on their Blog (I've added the link to your question).

Comment: Reach out to them if you don't like to get the data under a different license. CC BY-NC-SA by a .gov institution has "contact our partnerships team if you'd like to use this data for commercial purposes" written all over it.